# Is it possible to have grails test-app execute JUnit tests written in java?

Tags: grails

With grails 2.5, is it possible to write tests (unit and integration) in java and have them executed by the grails test runner (grails test-app)?

I'll provide a little background on our situation.  If we had a brand new app, we'd just write our tests as spock tests in groovy, and everything would be fine.  However, we have a large application that started out years ago as a Spring MVC application written in java.  We ported it to grails 2.1 about 3 years ago.  When we ported it into grails, parts of it were converted to groovy/grails, but much of it remained in java, including a lot of test code.  Since grails uses Spring MVC under the covers, we were able to get it to work without too much effort.   With grails 2.1, the grails test runner (grails test-app) does run our java tests for us without problems (they are all JUnit 4 tests).  However, we are now upgrading to grails 2.5, and we we run "grails test-app" with grails 2.5, only the groovy tests are executed--the java tests are all now ignored.  Does anyone know how to get grails to execute java tests in grails 2.5?

Here is an example integration test that runs under grails 2.1 but is just ignored with grails 2.5:

```
package com.finch.google.adwords.updaters;

import com.finch.domain.client.Client;
import com.finch.testing.DomainCreatorUtil;
import com.finch.testing.TestProfile;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.IfProfileValue;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


@IfProfileValue(name=TestProfile.INTEGRATION_WS, value=TestProfile.RUN)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/config/applicationContext.xml","/config/dbLocalPoolContext.xml","/config/testContext.xml"})
public class AccountUpdaterTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private DomainCreatorUtil mDcu;

    @Autowired
    private AccountUpdater mAccountUpdater;

    public void testDataPartitions() {
        Client client = mDcu.addNewTestClient();
        assertFalse(mAccountUpdater.confirmPartitions(client));
        mAccountUpdater.createPartitions(client);
        assertTrue(mAccountUpdater.confirmPartitions(client));
        mAccountUpdater.dropPartitions(client);
        assertFalse(mAccountUpdater.confirmPartitions(client));
    }
}
```

This test is located under the test/integration directory of the grails project (the standard place for grails tests).  We know that we can't leverage a lot of the nice testing functionality that grails provides with this sort of test, but these are legacy junit tests just testing java code, so that's fine--we just want them to run when we execute "grails test-app" like they did under grails 2.1.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in `./test/unit` folder? This should work automatically.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and it doesn't work.  After debugging into the grails test classes, it appears that the current grails test runner (as of grails 2.5.1) is looking for test files that end with the file extension ".groovy".  It looks to me like the test architecture is designed so that one could implement alternate test runners, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Here's the cause:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v2.5.0/grails-test/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/test/spock/GrailsSpecTestType.groovy#L62
Thanks, Graeme. Now to find a solution :-)

Comment: I did not find a solution. We ended up converting all of our java tests to groovy to workaround this issue.